# php mysql query fetch array even when no keyword is given

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like below;

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Sl |   Column1   |   Column2   |   Column3   |   Column4   |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1  |   Data1A    |   Data2A    |   Data3A    |   xxxxxx    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 2  |   Data1B    |   Data2B    |   Data3B    |   yyyyyy    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 3  |   Data1C    |   Data2C    |   Data3C    |   xxxxxx    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 4  |   Data1D    |   Data2D    |   Data3D    |   yyyyyy    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 5  |   Data1E    |   Data2E    |   Data3E    |   xxxxxx    |
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I have a query `$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1 LIKE'%$keyword%' AND Column4 = ''";`

I want to display results even if I am not giving any keyword for col4. But I can't avoid that part since I give some data for col4 sometime. btw I want to display the data even if I have nothing to check in col4. how can I make this possible?? My query should not look for col4 unless I provide xxxxxx or yyyyyy in the query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just change the query when you have data to check in col4?

```
if ($needToCheckColumn4) {
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1 LIKE'%$keyword%' AND Column4 = '$col4'";
} else {
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1 LIKE'%$keyword%'";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE Column1 LIKE'%$keyword%' AND Column4 LIKE '%$keyword2%'";
```

If $keyword2 is an empty string, it will match anything.

Comment: I want to use `=`, not `LIKE`

Comment: Then go with user138821's suggestion - although I would put $col4 in the if statement, as you don't need two variables.